# Tommy Castro / RL Burnside

Tags: identify-this-song, live-music

Does anyone know the name of the RL Burnside recording Tommy Castro plays (used to play?) before his live concerts? His websites offer contact info but those seem to be unplugged.

After attending many Tommy Castro concerts, that song is in my bones. Just heard randomly on radio and they mentioned Burnsides' name but not name of the song. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the tune you are thinking of might be "[It's Bad You Know](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QzC_rGX-XyM)," by R.L Burnside from the album, "Come On In." I found it by listening to the opening of live concert videos by Tommy Castro, and you can hear it in the background at 1:20 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gDdG3Krcdlk) as the band is taking the stage. Then looking for an R.L. Burnside recording with that harmonica riff on it. You are right, the track is hypnotizing! This [blog post](http://www.harpsurgery.com/its-bad-you-know-r-l-burnside/) claims it was used in an episode of "The Sopranos."